# How can I get information from one cell in a row, based on the clue of 2 other cells in the same row?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function, lookup

I'm trying to get Excel to give me information in `Column C` based on the values in `Columns A` and `B`.

Cell `A` and Cell `B` will contain duplicates, and what I'm trying to do is build a formula which finds a particular store (`Column A`), then finds the highest gross sales (Column B), and returns the date that the sales occurred (`Column C`).

I've thought about using a mixture of index and matches, if functions and row functions to deliver the outcome with no luck. So far I have:

`=MATCH("Wellington",A1:A8,0)` to tell me the first row that has Wellington as the city, `=MATCH(LARGE(B1:B8,1),B1:B8,0)` to tell me which row has the highest sales figures.

If I use the `AND` function I can get it to respond with `TRUE` - but I want it to tell me which row both apply in, so that I can use indexing to pull the date.

How can i accomplish this?

Comment: Try using `IF(AND(func1,func2),if true, if false)`

Comment: A picture is worth 1000 words. I know that you don’t have the privilege to post images yet, but can you give us a sample of what your data look like and what result you want to get, just by typing in enough rows of example data to illustrate the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Geez, I came up with an answer but there is probably an easier way to do it -

```
=INDEX(C1:C15,MATCH(MAX(IF(A1:A15=F1,1)*(B1:B15)),IF(A1:A15=F1,1)*(B1:B15),0))
```

The `F1` is your lookup value, it can be text if you want.

Enter the formula with your ranges and CSE <kbd>ctrl</kbd> <kbd>shft</kbd> <kbd>enter</kbd> because it's an array formula.

This is what it looks like on my sheet:

[image]

Comment: Oh and I don't know what to tell you if the maximum value occurs on more than one date, I guess make it another array and return the max date?

Answer (score 0):

The absolute easiest way to do this is to sort the data in descending order of sales and do a simple vlookup based on store name to return the date. It'll return the correct date because vlookup returns the first instance of the TRUE value.

If that's not possible then...

The following array formula gets the job done (**enter this formula by pressing Ctrl + Shift + ENTER**)

**=INDEX(Date,MATCH(lookup_value&MAX(IF(Name=lookup_value,Amount)),Name&Amount,0))**

where...

*Date* is the date range, which is your COLUMN B
*lookup_value* is whichever store you're looking up - your Column A
*Amount* is the range for the sales - your COLUMN C